# Can’t find all page tables when web scraping using r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table of tide data collected at 6 minute interval from a NOAA site using r.
I have tried a few different approaches but none seem to be able to find the table I am looking for:

```
page_adress<-"https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions.html?id=1612480&units=standard&bdate=20220204&edate=20220205&timezone=LST&clock=12hour&datum=MLLW&interval=6&action=data"

library(htmltab)
htmltab(doc = page_adress, which=1, header=0)

library(rvest)
html <- read_html(page_adress)

html %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table()
```

Both approaches can only find the short summary table on top of the page, but not the larger table requested.

```
> 1  5:18 AM high 1.89 ft.
2 12:11 PM  low 0.28 ft.
3  6:03 PM high 1.19 ft.
4 11:11 PM  low 0.67 ft.
```

If I inspect the code, I can see the long table data in the html document.
[image]

I am proficient to r but new to scraping, so I may be missing something obvious… any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You need to look at the page source, not the "Element" tab in the developer tools. The Elements tab shows the state of the page after javascript is run. `rvest` cannot run javascript for you. Most modern webpages use javascript to load data after the page itself loads. If you need to run javascript, you'll need to use a package like RSelenium or you'll need to reverse enginerr the javascript to find where the data is being loaded from. You cannot scrape the data directly from the page because it's just not in the page source.

Comment: Consider using the "rnoaa" package to access the information using the API then scraping the page.

Comment: You can just use the webservices button on the page. It gives you the actual API call (using the public CO-OPS Data API)  used for the content you requested. You would need to amend for a station that returns High/Low tides e.g. `station=1611443` and add in the `interval=hilo` e.g. `https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=predictions&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.WL&begin_date=20220206&end_date=20220207&datum=MLLW&station=1611443&time_zone=LST&units=english&interval=hilo&format=json` You can also alter the ending to csv or xml.

Answer (score 1):

Following MrFlick's answer the following obtains and formats the data for the larger table:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)

url <- "https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetter?product=predictions&begin_date=20220203&end_date=20220206&datum=MLLW&station=1612480&time_zone=LST&units=english&interval=6&format=json&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.TidePred"

headers <- c(
  'authority' = "tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov",
  'method' = "GET",
  'path' = "/api/prod/datagetter?product=predictions&begin_date=20220203&end_date=20220206&datum=MLLW&station=1612480&time_zone=LST&units=english&interval=6&format=json&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.TidePred",
  'scheme' = "https",
  'accept' = "*/*",
  'Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate",
  'referer' = "https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/",
  'User-Agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.17 Safari/537.36",
  'x-requested-with' = "XMLHttpRequest"
)

h1 <- httr::handle('')

table <- url %>%
  httr::GET(.,
            httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
            handle = h1
  ) %>%
  content() %>%
  map_dfr(., pluck, .id = NULL) %>%
  set_names("Date", "Prediction") %>%
  mutate(Time = format(as.POSIXct(Date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"%H:%M")) %>%
  mutate(Date = format(as.POSIXct(Date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  mutate(`Day of the Week` = wday(strptime(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), label = TRUE)) %>%
  select(Date, `Day of the Week`, Time, Prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jsonlite` package,

```
url = 'https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetter?product=predictions&begin_date=20220203&end_date=20220206&datum=MLLW&station=1612480&time_zone=LST&units=english&interval=6&format=json&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.TidePred'

library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(url)
$predictions
                   t      v
1   2022-02-03 00:00  0.431
2   2022-02-03 00:06  0.485
3   2022-02-03 00:12  0.540
4   2022-02-03 00:18  0.596
5   2022-02-03 00:24  0.653
6   2022-02-03 00:30  0.710
7   2022-02-03 00:36  0.768
8   2022-02-03 00:42  0.826
9   2022-02-03 00:48  0.885
10  2022-02-03 00:54  0.944
11  2022-02-03 01:00  1.003
```